# Can we merge an account of many users in the same service into one firebase account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

There are many people who own multiple facebook or twitter accounts. And maybe they would like to merge their accounts in another service

Such as, I have 2 facebook accounts and want to access a game from both account. So if one account got deleted, I can login another to got access to the same

Is it possible in firebase? And how could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Firebase Auth supports that via the [Account Linking API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

1. User login into Firebase with the first Facebook account.
2. getCurrentUser() gives you the Firebase user.
3. Prompt the user to login with second Facebook account.
4. Link the second Facebook token:

> getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(facebookTokenCredential)

Comment: I know there are Account Linking API. My point is, is it possible to link multiple facebook account into one firebase account

Comment: As you might know, a person could have multiple twitter account. Some people may have 2 facebook accounts reserved for one got banned or hacked. Something like that

Comment: Multiple facebook accounts can be linked into the same Firebase account. Same for Twitter or Google accounts.

If you have tried and it does not work, please file a bug report to Firebase.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For the moment that is not possible. Firebase set an uuid for each facebook account when login for first time.